# Good allocator for cross thread allocation and free

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management

I am planning to write a C++ networked application where:

1. I use a single thread to accept TCP connections and also to read data from them. I am planning to use epoll/select to do this. The data is written into buffers that are allocated using some arena allocator say jemalloc.
2. Once there is enough data from a single TCP client to form a protocol message, the data is published on a ring buffer. The ring buffer structures contain the fd for the connection and a pointer to the buffer containing the relevant data.
3. A worker thread processes entries from the ring buffers and sends some result data to the client. After processing each event, the worker thread frees the actual data buffer to return it to the arena allocator for re use.

I am leaving out details on how the publisher makes data written by it visible to the worker thread.

So my question is: Are there any allocators which optimize for this kind of behavior i.e. allocating objects on one thread and freeing on another?

I am worried specifically about having to use locks to return memory to an arena which is not the thread affinitized arena. I am also worried about false sharing since the producer thread and the worker thread will both write to the same region. Seems like jemalloc or tcmalloc both don't optimize for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you go down the path of implementing a highly optimized allocator for your multi-threaded application, you should first just use the standard `new` and `delete` operators for your implementation. After you have a correct implementation of your application, you can move to address bottlenecks that are discovered through profiling it.

If you get to the stage where it is obvious that the standard `new` and `delete` allocators are a bottleneck to the application, the following is the approach I have used:

**Assumption:** The number of threads are fixed and are statically created.

- Each thread has their own arena.
- Each object taken from an arena has a reference back to the arena it came from.
- Each arena has a separate garbage list for each thread.
- When a thread frees an object, it goes back the arena it came from, but is placed in the thread specific garbage list.
- The thread that actually owns the arena treats its garbage list as the real free list.
- Periodically, the thread that owns an arena performs a garbage collection pass to fold objects from the other thread garbage lists into the real free list.

The "periodical" garbage collection pass doesn't necessarily have to be time based. A subset of the garbage could be reaped on every allocation and free, for example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your assumption is correct. I start all threads right in the beginning and their number never changes. This seems like a good thing to try. Like you noted I haven't benchmarked anything. I will definitely do that before I start optimizing anything.

Comment: The lock contention should not be too much of an issue.  The time that the lock has to be held is very small compared with the time taken to process image data - just enough to push the small 'fd+buffer pointer' struct onto whatever queue/container you use.  Same with returning them to some pool for re-use.

Comment: @MartinJames: The question itself has broader applicability than the use case of the asker. I have already warned the asker to not to try to implement something this complicated unless the application is proven to require it. Someone else's application may require something like this, and their searching may take them here.

Comment: @MartinJames. You might be right about the time it takes to return a buffer to a pool under the lock being small compared to the actual image processing. I intentionally did not mention image processing in the original question and was vague with the protocol message's contents to know of a solution in case this was a problem. Also I am not using locks to change or read my ring buffer structs. I am using relaxed atomics since there is a single writer.

Comment: @bop It is to allow memory to be allocated by one thread, to be freed by a different thread without a lock.

Comment: @JohnPaul Each thread specific garbage list would have to be implemented using a lock free data structure and algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to deal with memory allocation and deallocation issues is to not deal with it.

You mention a ring buffer. Those are usually a fixed size. If you can come up with a fixed maximum size for your protocol messages you can allocate all the memory you will ever need at program start. When deallocating, keep the memory but reset it to a fresh state.

Now, your program may need to allocate and deallocate memory while dealing with each message but that will be done in each thread and cross-thread issues will not come into play.

This can work even if your message maximum size is too large to preallocate if you can allocate the amount of memory that *most* messages will use and have handlers for allocating more when necessary.

Comment: This works well if all threads behave symmetrically. But if the design is such that certain threads always allocate certain types that are always freed by threads that never allocate those types, this technique will make the program behave like it is leaking memory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My application deals with images of varying sizes. My ring buffer preallocates all objects like you noted. This takes care of not having to create new objects and free them. Besides this state, the ring buffer entries also contain a pointer to a  buffer that contains an image. These buffers cannot be preallocated because the maximum size limit is way too high.